# Inequality question---Max and Min

Tags: inequality

$f(x,y)=\max\left\{x,y,\frac 1x + \frac 1y\right\}$, where x and y are positive real numbers.

What is the smallest possible value of $f$

Comment: Have you made any progress on this question?

Comment: I've tried x=y, so the smallest value would be root 2. Now, I'm considering x>y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x,y)=k$.

Thus, $x\leq k$, $y\leq k$ and
$$\frac{2}{k}\leq\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}\leq k,$$ which gives
$$k^2\geq2$$ or $$k\geq\sqrt2.$$
The equality occurs for $$x=y=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}=\sqrt2,$$
which says that $\sqrt2$ is a minimal value.

Comment: Thanks! Brilliant solution.

Comment: @ggkkll You are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Assume without loss of generality that $x\geq y $. Then the question is equivalent to finding the minimum value of $max (x,\frac {1}{x}+\frac {1}{y})) $. Now, because of the new assumption, we get $1/x+1/y\geq 2/x $so the minimum value would be of the form $max (x,2/x) $. I leave it to you to calculate the exact minimum value :)

Comment: i think you must consider all possible cases

Comment: and what is if $$x<y$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner That's obvious: $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$ and $y>x$ so already covered.

Comment: Thanks! @Or Kedar